# Automation tool: Read excel input and generate request body and generate response and compare response in excel sheet

Tags: java, automation

Did anyone make any automation tool in java in which we read excel sheet row as a input and pass it to json in request body and then generate a respnse and compare the response in excel sheet row and then generate a excel sheet as a ouput pass or fail for particular ID. Can anyone please guide me what to refer and how to proceed for this

Comment: the best java library AFAIK to read and write into excel files is Apache POI

Comment: @shikida Can you tell me how to compare the Json response with the excel sheet. Lets suppose you get a response with [ Id: 28, name: genie, class: A] you have to traverse the whole excel sheet to find the correct match with respect to all three fields.  Id, name and class.. then how it can be achieved

Comment: JSON will be probably easier for you to handle, or if your excel file has no formulas, you can dump the excel data into a CSV format, which is more programming language friendly. Most probably, CSV is faster than JSON which is faster than Excel.